# Update password option through rxjava and retrofit does not work

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, android-livedata

I want to create change password option for my app which will update the current password with new pasword and Im using rxjava and retrofit to send a update request to server. Sorry if Im having issues with the correct terminologies. Im new to android. Issue im having is Validations I have added to viewmodel does not work properly. I think its because of the fragment class not configured properly. im having trouble with setting it to to show error messages(such as "Old Password is required" and "New Password is required") which should be validated by the viewmodel and change password according to that. 
Im currently getting a "cannot resolve method maketext" error from the Toast I have made in the fragment class.
Any help with this matter is highly appreciated.Please find my code here. Also please let me know if my approach is correct or how it can be improved.

UpdatePasswordFragment.java

```
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UpdatePasswordViewModel.class);
        binding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
        //mViewModel.setUser(new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.INTENT_USER), User.class));
        mViewModel.setUser(new Gson().fromJson(getArguments().getString("user"), User.class));

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        mViewModel.getMessage().observe(this, s -> {
            Toast.makeText(this,s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
    }
```

UpdatePassowrdViewModel.java

```
public class UpdatePasswordViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private Repository Repository;
    Application application;


    public void init(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        showSpinner.setValue(false);

        Repository = new Repository(application);
        updatePasswordMutableLiveData.setValue(new UpdatePassword());
    }

    private MutableLiveData<UpdatePassword> updatePasswordMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> showSpinner = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private final String SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Password Successfully Changed";
    private User mUser;

    public MutableLiveData<String> getOldPassword() {
        return oldPassword;
    }

    public void setOldPassword(MutableLiveData<String> oldPassword) {
        this.oldPassword = oldPassword;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getNewPassword() {
        return newPassword;
    }

    public void setNewPassword(MutableLiveData<String> newPassword) {
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getConfirmNewPassword() {
        return confirmNewPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmNewPassword(MutableLiveData<String> confirmNewPassword) {
        this.confirmNewPassword = confirmNewPassword;
    }

    private MutableLiveData<String> oldPassword = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<String> newPassword = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<String> confirmNewPassword = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> showLoader = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.mUser = user;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    private MutableLiveData<String> message = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getShowLoader() {
        return showLoader;
    }




    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public void changePassword() {
        showSpinner.setValue(true);

        Repository.changePassword(mUser.getUserName(), oldPassword.getValue(),newPassword.getValue())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(s -> {
                    if(SUCCESS_MESSAGE.equals(s)) {
                        oldPassword.setValue("");
                        newPassword.setValue("");
                        confirmNewPassword.setValue("");
                    }

                    showSpinner.setValue(false);
                    message.setValue(s.toString());
                }, throwable -> {
                    showSpinner.setValue(false);
                    message.setValue(throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                });


    }


    public void  savePasswordClicked(View view) {
        if(oldPassword.getValue().trim().length() == 0) {
            message.setValue("Old Password is required");
            return;
        }

        if(newPassword.getValue().trim().length() == 0) {
            message.setValue("New Password is required");
            return;
        }

        if(!newPassword.getValue().equals(confirmNewPassword.getValue())) {
            message.setValue("New Password and Confirm Password doesn't match");
            return;
        }
        changePassword();
    }
```

Repository.Java

```
 public Observable<ApiResponse<User>> changePassword(String userId, String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
       // return mApi.updatePassword(UpdatePassword);
        return mApi.updatePassword(userId,oldPassword, newPassword );
    }
```

THis is the retrofit call I have made in the APi

```
   @PUT("user/updatepassword")
    Observable<ApiResponse<User>> updatePassword(
            @Field("currentPassword") String oldPassword,
            @Field("newPassword") String newPassword,
            @Field("userId") String userId
    );
```

Comment: Appreciate the tip. I think I have pinpoint the issue to fragment class and I have edited the comment according to that. Hope this will give a clear picture

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using not only ViewModel here, but data binding too. First thing you need to do to be able to use data binding is to add to your `build.gradle` the following:

```
// enable data binding for app here
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Second mistake is that you are making setters and getters for `MutableLiveData`, you should change the value of the data by calling `.setValue(newValue)`, the reference of the object should be immutable if you want your observers to be notified of change.

The last thing you need to do is to make sure the required fields are binded correctly in you layout, in your case you need a two-way binding, example:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
    android:checked="@={viewmodel.rememberMe}"
/>
```

You can read more about two-way data binding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have already set out the binding in build gradle and layout also set out as per the instructions. But im still not getting the second mistake you have mentioned.  Did you meant the set values of changePassword method of viewModel? Would you be able to explain by an example?